# Get id of html tag in another php file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database table `Library` and I have fetched image `src` from the table and gave the name of the image tag as `id` from the table as `name=".$idRow."`.

So what i want to do is that when the user clicks on an image id of the image from the table should be passed in the name of that image tag, which is successfully done.

But when i pass that id through a variable using session (`$_SESSION['sessionBookId']=$idRow;`) to another `PHP` file only the last id of the book is passed through that variable.

I want to pass the id of the image clicked but only the last id is passed. 
Is there a solution?

```
<?php    
    $sqlSelectImage = "SELECT * FROM Library WHERE 1";
    $queryExec = mysqli_query($link, $sqlSelectImage);

    while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_object($queryExec)) {
        $idRow=stripcslashes($rs->id);

?>
<tr>
    //image tag
    <td align="center">
    <?php 
        echo "<a href=".'book-view.php'." name=".$idRow.">";
        $_SESSION['sessionBookId']=$idRow;
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo stripcslashes($rs->book_url); ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
    <?php echo"</a>" ?>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <form action="" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="buy" name="bookView"/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['bookView'])) {
        header("Location:book-view.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
<td align="center"><?php echo "<a href=\"book-view.php?id=$idRow\">";?><img src="<?php echo stripcslashes($rs->book_url); ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></a></td>
```

in the book-view.php you can access to passes value with

```
$_GET['id']
```

in the way you can pass variable with GET

Comment: what is id? shouldn't I do $_GET['$idRow'] rather than $_GET['id']?

Comment: you should use $_GET['id'] because we passed id to book-view.php, in the a tag "<a href=\"book-view.php?id=$idRow\">"

Comment: you can change id name which i used in the a tag and replace that which name which you need

Answer (score 0):

```
<td align="center"><?php echo "<a href=".'book-view.php'." name=".$idRow.">"; $_SESSION['sessionBookId']=$idRow;?><img src="<?php echo stripcslashes($rs->book_url); ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><?php echo"</a>" ?></td>
```

In your pass url link the `$idRow` is assignd to `$_SESSION['sessionBookId']`
what you should do is you should equal the book id to some name to GET in the page of `book-view.php`

right method is

```
<td align="center"><?php echo "<a href=".'book-view.php?'."id=".$idRow.">"; ?><img src="<?php echo stripcslashes($rs->book_url); ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><?php echo"</a>" ?></td>
```

You can capture the value of id by `$_GET['id'];`

Use **mysql_real_escape_string()** while capture the value for id `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);`

check the manual for [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Instead of **id** you can use **whatever_name** but when you GET the value please use like  `$_GET['whatever_name ']`

I just explain it will help some one in future.

Comment: $_GET[$idRow] is what i should be doing?

Comment: it will capture the value of id you send with the href <?php echo "<a href=".'book-view.php?'."id=".$idRow.">"; ?>